# Call a SOAP WebService from a Stored Procedure (SQL Server 2012 - Can't use CLR!)

Tags: sql-server

I'm looking for an Stored Procedure to make a SOAP request. Pass in a SOAP envelope.
**I can not use a CLR**. I have seen countless SP to but all return a 202 and nothing is processed.

*https://www.codeproject.com/articles/428200/how-to-invoke-a-web-service-from-a-stored-procedure
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-call-web-service-using-sql*

Where and how can I make a SOAP request from SQL Server 2012+ in T-SQL ?  Any examples would help.

thanks in advance

Comment: XY problem. DB is not the place to run a SOAP request

Comment: If the existing approaches with MSXML don't do it for you, then you now know why calling a URL from the DB is a bad idea -- troubleshooting is a big pain. For an alternative, assuming you can't change your callers to invoke the service in the first place, have your stored procedure insert requests in a Service Broker queue, and use an external application to process requests from that queue. This is far better in terms of maintenance and scalability.

Comment: Short answer - you can't. You can (and did) use the ole automation procedures - which are strongly advised against, error-prone, fragile, and difficult to debug / diagnose. You rule out CLR, so you have reached a dead end. Choose a different path as already suggested.